# How can Ionic Cordova Android App Published to HuaWei App Gallery?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, huawei-developers

I've read through some documents and it mentioned about changes of package name. What are the changes required to perform if I want to publish ionic cordova android app to HuaWei app gallery?

1. Change of package name?
2. Signing of the app?

Answer (score 2):

There are  no restrictions on the Cordova apps. They can be released on HUAWEI AppGallery.

**How to release an app:**

1. Register and sign in to your HUAWEI Developer account, go to AppGallery Connect, create a new app, and upload the APK.
2. Set languages and basic app information, such as app name, introduction, screenshots, and app category.
3. Select your business model (free or premium), release countries and regions, and a link to the privacy statement.
4. Confirm that all of the information provided is correct, and submit your app for review.

Please also refer to [AppGallery Review Guidelines](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/30202?ha_source=hms1).

---

Just a point to take care. If your app has integrated GMS Kit, these capabilities provided via GMS are not available on Huawei phones with HMS. If you want your app to run on these phones, integrate [Huawei Mobile Services (HMS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/?ha_source=hms1).

Huawei has provided some HMS Core kit plugins for Cordova. They have been published to public open source communities. You can also find them on [GitHub](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-cordova-plugin).

[Account Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/about-the-service-0000001051006397?ha_source=hms1)

[Ads Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050437673?ha_source=hms1)

[Analytics Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050134725?ha_source=hms1)

[In-App Purchases Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050132986?ha_source=hms1)

[Location Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050140246?ha_source=hms1)

[Map Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050329204?ha_source=hms1)

[ML Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050765773?ha_source=hms1)

[Push Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050135701?ha_source=hms1)

[Scan Kit plugin for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/introduction-0000001057398487-V1?ha_source=hms1)

[Site Kit plugins for Cordova](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050260022?ha_source=hms1)

Take Cordova Push Plugin as an example, if you need to integrate it:

1. Install HMS Core (APK): You need to download and install HMS Core (APK) 4.0.2.300 or later on your device.
2. Install the Android SDK
3. Configure App Information in AppGallery Connect: Including creating an app, generating a signing certificate fingerprint, generating a signature file, obtaining the SHA-256 fingerprint from signature file, configuring the signing certificate fingerprint, enabling required services.
4. Integrate Plugin with Ionic

a. Install Ionic CLI.

b. Create a Ionic project or use the existing Ionic project.

c. Enable the Cordova integration if haven't done before

```
ionic integrations enable cordova
```

d. Update the widget **id** property which is specified in the **config.xml** file. It must be same with **client** > **package_name** value of the **agconnect-services.json** file.

e. Add the **Android platform** to the project if haven't done before.

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

f. Install HMS Push plugin to the project.

g. Check whether the Cordova Push Plugin is successfully added to **<project_root>/plugins** directory

h. Copy **agconnect-services.json** file to **<project_root>/platforms/android/app** directory.

i. Add **keystore(.jks)** and **build.json** files to your project's root directory.

j. Run the application.

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

For more, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/cordova-intro-0000001050735015?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: If I have enabled Huawei Android (HMS) Configuration in One Signal, can I still use Cordova One Signal plugin or I must use cordova-plugin-hms-push?

Comment: You need to use cordova-plugin-hms-push to get token from Huawei devices and OneSignal will use the token to send messages.